# How to set program name in ibatis config XML?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ibatis, apache-commons-dbcp

I am attempting to set the program name to something other than "jdbc thin client" using the iBatis dao config.

From my dao XML config file:

```
<transactionManager type="JDBC">
    <dataSource type="DBCP">
        <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.foo.bar.jdbc.MyOracleDriver"/>
        <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver&amp;jdbc:oracle:thin:@${host}:1521:${database}"/>
        <property name="JDBC.Username" value="${userName}"/>
        <property name="JDBC.Password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="Pool.DefaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="Pool.MaximumActiveConnections" value="63"/>
        <property name="Pool.MaximumIdleConnections" value="10"/>
        <property name="Pool.MaximumWait" value="2000"/>
        <property name="Pool.ValidationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
        <property name="Pool.testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="Pool.TestOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="Pool.LogAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="Pool.RemoveAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="Pool.RemoveAbandonedTimeout" value="300"/>
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```

I would assume this is as easy as adding the following:

```
<property name="v$session.program" value="My Program Name"/>
```

But that didn't work. The program name did not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear. What does your program name have to do with your transaction manager configuration? Where do you see this program name, is this your own program or a product you downloaded?

Comment: I am viewing the session details in TOAD's session browser.